# How to call variadic function in erc223 contract

Tags: truffle, erc-20, erc-223

There is two transfer function in my contract,
And i m trying to call transfer function of erc223 for transfer token to contract address using this function.

```
 Token.deployed()
 .then(function(i) {
   i.transfer.call('0x5f71b35ed4bdd29d0183b5a11d0b3dfd025d7556','12','test_data')
   .then(function(j){
     console.log(j)
   })
 })
```

but it throw an error as below:

> (node:12048) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 6): Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function

Answer (score 0):

The transfer function is not constant so you should call it from a transaction not a call

```
Token.deployed()
.then(function(i) {
    i.transfer.sendTransaction('0x5f71b35ed4bdd29d0183b5a11d0b3dfd025d7556', '12', 'test_data')
    .then(function(j) {
         console.log(j)
    })
})
```